# Minimum required version of iOS for Chalkduster font

Tags: ios, fonts

What is the minimum required version of iOS for Chalkduster font. When was chalkduster font introduced in iOS. Was it there all along

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Chalkduster is present on iPad since 4.0 and iPhone since 5.0.

See fonts for 4.0 [here](http://www.prepressure.com/fonts/basics/ios-4-fonts) and fonts for 5.0 [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4980)